# How to count amount of unique elements in an array of structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, element, counting

I have a structure:

```
struct wordItem
{
   string word;
   int count;
};
```

I'm reading in a text file with many different words and storing them into an array.

```
    ifstream inputFile("data.txt");
    if(inputFile.is_open())
    {
         while(getline(inputFile, data, ' '))
         {
         wordItemList[i].word = data;
         i++;
         }
    }
```

My question is what is the best way to count each time a word appears in the array. For example if my data.txt file was

```
the fox jumped over the fence
```

I want to be able to store how many times each word appears within the struct within the "int count;"

Comment: You need a data structure to map a word to a counter. In C++ we have std::map. If this is homework you should tell us what your level of progress is, maybe a std::map is not yet an option to you.

Comment: [`std::map<std::string, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Concur with Cornstalks. [Something like this](http://pastebin.com/JnGnwyfp). Apologies in advance for any syntax errors. Change every `unordered_map` to `map` if you want ordering). Yes, it really is that simple. In short, you don't really need that structure; the map will hold the count for your as the mapped-to value.

Comment: C++ does not have structures. You have a _class_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifstream inputFile("data.txt");
if(!inputFile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Can't open data.txt\n";
    exit(0);
}

map<string, int> freq;
while(getline(inputFile, word, ' '))
    ++freq[word];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `std::multiset` or `std::unordered_multiset`. The performance depends a bit on your data set so some tuning is required to find the best one in practice. Something like this would work (adapt with your file reading code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {

    std::unordered_multiset<string> dict;

    for (auto&& s : {"word1", "word2", "word1"}) {
       dict.insert(s);
    }

    std::cout << dict.count("word1") << std::endl; // prints 2
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on the data set & size, you could also use a more optimised data structure for storing & comparing strings, such as a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but this is not available in the standard, or `boost` and most of the times is a bit of an overkill IMHO (although you can find [some implementations](http://www.seqan.de/)).